# Sonatype Nexus 3 - Raw Repository - Custom Asset Attributes

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

does anyone know if there is a way to define custom attributes for assets in raw repositories?

Thanks.
Malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to support this is not possible yet, but may be a feature which gets implemented by Q4/16.